# ActiveRecord ::create returns record with ID = 0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, tdd, factory-bot

I'm having an issue when creating an object with Rails (noticed it when attempting to create an instance with FactoryGirl, where the returned model has `id=0`, even though it is getting properly persisted and has the right ID in the DB. Other factories are working fine, and this one seems no different. Of note is that the model is backed by a DB view not an actual table, but other models with this same "condition" are working correctly. Any ideas?

My model is:

```
class Property::Openhouse < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name  = 'property_open_houses_view'
  self.primary_key = 'id'


  belongs_to :property, :inverse_of => :openhouses
  attr_protected #allow access to all params

  # [SNIP]
end
```

The factory:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :open_house, class: 'Property::Openhouse' do
    property
    mls_system { property.mls_system }
    mls_num { property.mls_num }
    event_date 1.week.from_now
    start_time "10:00AM"
    end_time "6:00PM"
  end
end
```

What happens in IRB (or tests):

```
development (main):0 > Property::Openhouse.count
   (0.5ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `property_open_houses_view`
=> 5
development (main):0 > oh = FactoryGirl.create :open_house
=> #<Property::Openhouse id: 0, property_id: 8, mls_num: "V123460", mls_system: :abcdef, event_date: "2014-04-24 19:57:27", start_time: "10:00AM", end_time: "6:00PM", remarks: nil, created_at: "2014-04-17 21:05:15", updated_at: "2014-04-17 21:05:15", open_house_type: nil, most_recent_import_id: nil, expired_at: nil>
development (main):0 > oh.persisted?
=> true
development (main):0 > oh.id
=> 0
development (main):0 > Property::Openhouse.last
  Property::Openhouse Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `property_open_houses_view`.* FROM `property_open_houses_view` ORDER BY `property_open_houses_view`.`id` DESC LIMIT 1
=> #<Property::Openhouse id: 6, property_id: 8, mls_num: "V123460", mls_system: "abcdef", event_date: "2014-04-24 19:57:27", start_time: "10:00AM", end_time: "6:00PM", remarks: nil, created_at: "2014-04-17 21:05:15", updated_at: "2014-04-17 21:05:15", open_house_type: nil, most_recent_import_id: nil, expired_at: nil>
development (main):0 > Property::Openhouse.count
   (0.5ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `property_open_houses_view`
=> 6
```

Any ideas?

**UPDATE**: I am using MySQL and the view is backedby a single table

```
CREATE VIEW property_open_houses_view AS
SELECT

`id`,
`property_id`,
`mls_num`,
`event_date`,
`start_time`,
`end_time`,
`remarks`,
`created_at`,
`updated_at`,
`open_house_type`

FROM property_open_houses;
```

**UPDATE Apr 21, 2014**

Following the suggestion from @Aaron K, I looked into https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/5982, but I'm afraid that might not be my case either, since my table definition does not have `default 0` for the ID.

```
# db/schema.rb
create_table "property_open_houses", :force => true do |t|
  t.string   "mls_system",            :limit => 30, :null => false
  t.integer  "property_id",                         :null => false
  t.datetime "entered_at"
  t.datetime "modified_at"
  t.string   "mls_num",               :limit => 30, :null => false
  t.datetime "event_date"
  t.string   "end_time",              :limit => 30
  t.string   "start_time",            :limit => 30
  t.string   "open_house_type",       :limit => 30
  t.text     "remarks"
  t.string   "remote_sysid"
  t.datetime "created_at",                          :null => false
  t.datetime "updated_at",                          :null => false
  t.integer  "most_recent_import_id"
  t.datetime "expired_at"
end
```

I checked both in `schema.rb` as well as directly in the database, where the ID in the underlying table is an autoincrementing, non-null, primary key integer. My `schema.rb` does not include views, we generate them through a rake task that gets run automatically after `db:migrate` which drops the existing view and recreates it by running the raw SQL shown in my previous update. Interestingly, if I run `describe property_open_houses_view;` on MySQL, the ID field is listed as Default 0. However, for another table/view pair that I have, even though the same output (ID default 0) shows up in the `describe`, the Factory Girl models are returned with the appropriate ID.

Incorrect behaviour:

```
mysql> describe property_open_houses_view;
+-----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field           | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id              | int(11)     | NO   |     | 0       |       |
 ... SNIP ...

mysql> describe property_open_houses;
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field           | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id              | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
 ... SNIP ...
```

Correct behaviour:

```
mysql> describe properties_view;
+---------------------------+----------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field                     | Type           | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------------------------+----------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id                        | int(11)        | NO   |     | 0       |       |
 ... SNIP ...

mysql> describe properties;
+---------------------------+----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field                     | Type           | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------------------+----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                        | int(11)        | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
 ... SNIP ...
```

One thing I did notice is that when I create an instance of the model that behaves correctly (`Property`), the resulting SQL `INSERT` has no `id` field, but in the misbehaving one (`Property::Openhouse`), there is such a field, and it is getting provided with a value of 0, which is ignored by the DB which replaces it with the next autoincrementing value.

```
SQL (1.1ms)  INSERT INTO `property_open_houses_view` (`created_at`, `end_time`, 
`event_date`, `expired_at`, `id`, `mls_num`, `mls_system`, `most_recent_import_id`, 
`open_house_type`, `property_id`, `remarks`, `start_time`, `updated_at`) VALUES 
('2014-04-21 15:03:25', '6:00PM', '2014-04-14 15:02:27', NULL, 0, 'V123456', 'abcdef',
NULL, NULL, 1032366, NULL, '10:00AM', '2014-04-21 15:03:25')
```

**UPDATE Apr 21, 2014 Part 2**

I just realized that FactoryGirl does not seem to be part of the equation, and have thus updated the question title. Creating the model with `create` raises the same situation

```
development (main):0 > oh = Property::Openhouse.create(property_id: p.id, mls_num: p.mls_num, mls_system: p.mls_system)
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.9ms)  INSERT INTO `property_open_houses_view` (`created_at`, `end_time`, `event_date`, `expired_at`, `id`, `mls_num`, `mls_system`, `most_recent_import_id`, `open_house_type`, `property_id`, `remarks`, `start_time`, `updated_at`) VALUES ('2014-04-21 15:20:37', NULL, NULL, NULL, 0, 'V123457', 'abcdef', NULL, NULL, 1032367, NULL, NULL, '2014-04-21 15:20:37')
   (28.2ms)  COMMIT
=> #<Property::Openhouse id: 0, property_id: 1032367, mls_num: "V123457", mls_system: :abcdef, event_date: nil, start_time: nil, end_time: nil, remarks: nil, created_at: "2014-04-21 15:20:37", updated_at: "2014-04-21 15:20:37", open_house_type: nil, most_recent_import_id: nil, expired_at: nil>
```

Comment: Which database are you using?  And is the view backed by only a single table?

Comment: I'm using MySQL and it is backed by a single table. I have updated the question with this.

Answer (score 0):

Most databases do not allow you to insert directly into a view. There are some exceptions (such as if the view is backed by a single table). For example, PostgreSQL will raise the following error when you attempt to `INSERT` on a view:

> ERROR:  cannot insert into view "myview"
>
> DETAIL:  Views that do not select from a single table or view are not automatically updatable.
>
> HINT:  To enable inserting into the view, provide an `INSTEAD OF INSERT` trigger or an unconditional `ON INSERT DO INSTEAD` rule.

Other databases will probably behave differently, so consult their documentation.

Continuing with PostgreSQL (and Rails 4.0.x). When `ActiveRecord` does a `create`, the SQL looks like the following:

```
INSERT INTO "mytable" ("created_at", "foo", "updated_at", "bar")
VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4)
RETURNING "id"
[
  ["created_at", Thu, 17 Apr 2014 23:17:32 UTC +00:00],
  ["foo", "testing"],
  ["updated_at", Thu, 17 Apr 2014 23:17:32 UTC +00:00],
  ["bar", 4.0]
]
```

The important part is the `RETURNING "id"`. Here ActiveRecord is sent back the `id` value of the created row. Ensure that if your view is using a rule to pretend to allow `create`, that the SQL has the appropriate `RETURNING` syntax for your database.

### Edit - MySQL DB

It seems that this may actually be a known issue with MySQL and Rails. See https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/5982 for the full issue.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think that's the case here. I am using MySQL and it's a single table backed view. I have other models backed by views that are not presenting the same problem :(

Comment: @RuyDiaz I updated the answer, but seems this may be a known problem: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/5982

Comment: great suggestion. But it seems like that's not the issue either. I have updated my question with more details.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? I'm having a similar problem (https://github.com/eddiej/sql_views)

Comment: @EddieJohnston I don't see how that repo applies to this. You've setup your system to generate 0 ids. See this issue I opened: https://github.com/eddiej/sql_views/issues/1